# Inserting Tab in sed

Tags: macos, shell, sed

I am using protractor to run some UI sanity tests on chrome.

I have three shared variables in my pageobject whose values I have to change through a shell script using sed.

The variables are like:

```
      this.var = x

      this.y = y
```

I want sed to change the value of these variables by taking into account the tabs.

I have currently removed the tabs and my sed command looks like this.

sed -i '' 's/^this.var=.*/this.var=true;/'

How can I change this command to take into consideration the tabs.

Comment: I don't want to do a large edit because I might be missing the question, but I don't believe this has anything to do with javascript, selenium, jasmine, or protractor. I would rewrite the question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of these variables in shell and not in your JavaScript / TypeScript? It might make more sense to keep track and manage it in your Protractor test since the hosting OS might not have sed available. Also, if you want to do sed, there needs to have more context of what you are using it for. Maybe the alternative solution (not using sed) is easier?

Comment: @ben Sorry, I will rewrite the question.

Comment: @cnishina. The reason for that is the website I am testing on uses a configuration file of its own in a cluster. Since I can't change it directly from my local machine. I am assuming some values to check for certain use cases. This is why I change the values of these three variables through the shell

Answer (score 0):

please, can you put your sed command as code sample? Which tab do you mean? At the beginning of line? In example above there are spaces at the beginning of line. Your sed don't work with example since spaces are around `=` and `-i ''`. In sed one can use `\t` for tab. So:

```
sed 's/^\tthis.var = .*/this.var=true;/'
```